# How do you solve this Cauchy problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Consider on $(0,+\infty)$ the differential equation
\begin{align}
\label{eq}
x^2y''(x)+xy'(x)+y(x)=10\ . \quad\quad(1)
\end{align}
For a twice derivable function $y:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, define $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as
\begin{align}
u(t)=y\left(e^t\right).
\end{align}
And $u$ satisfies $$u''(x)+u(x)=10.\quad\quad (2)$$

How do I solve the following Cauchy problem using $(2)$?
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x^2y''(x)+xy'(x)+y(x)=10\\
y(1)=0\\
y'(1)=-2
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

$$u''(t)+u(t)=10.\quad\quad (2)$$
Characteristic polynomial is $$r^2+1=(r-i)(r+i)=0$$
$$\implies r=\pm i$$
Therefore the solution of the homogeneous DE is:
$$u_h(t)=c_1\cos t +c_2\sin t$$
For the particular solution choose=
$$u_p=A \implies u_p=10$$
$$u(t)=c_1\cos t +c_2\sin t+10$$
Now you now that $x=e^t \implies t=\ln x$
So that:
$$y(x)=c_1\cos (\ln x) +c_2\sin (\ln x)+10$$
Apply the given initial conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Now you know that
$$
u(t)=10+A\cos t+B\sin t
$$
or
$$
y(x)=10+A\cos(\ln x)+B\sin(\ln x)
$$
and you determine the constants from the initial conditions, $y(1)=10+A$, $y'(1)=B$.